# mapStateToProps returns no data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my top-level component App.js, I have

```
 componentWillMount() {
    let data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let todayURL = 'http://www.someURL.com/';
      let viewDate = moment()
        .add(1, 'years')
        .add(i, 'days')
        .format('MMM-DD');

      let date = moment()
        .add(1, 'years')
        .add(i, 'days')
        .format('YYYY-MMM-DD');

      let cardURL =
        todayURL +
        moment()
          .add(1, 'years')
          .add(i, 'days')
          .format('YYYY/MMM-DD.png');

      data.push({
        id: i,
        date,
        uri: cardURL
      });
    }

    store.dispatch({ type: 'data_generated', payload: data });
```

My reducer is handled this way:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
case 'data_generated':
      return { ...state, calendarData: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I combine my reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import CalendarReducer from './CalendarReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  calendarData: CalendarReducer
});
```

The idea behind this is to have an initial dataset that the app can use and persist.

In a child component that displays the information in the dataset I access state:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props)
   return( blah blah);
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { calendarData: state.calendarData };
}; 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

But when I console log I see an empty array:

[image]

This is a React Native app using React Navigation.

What's going on?

Comment: You need to add some code or it will be impossible to figure out what's wrong. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MichaelCheng Done! Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you combing the reducer? if yes,  can you show us that code also?

Comment: thanks for adding the combineReducer. Now, where are you printing the object? The code of that

Comment: @MatthewBarbara thanks for your patience.  I'm just console logging `this.props` in render

Comment: add a console llog in the reducer to debug -  ```export default (state = [], action) => {
case 'data_generated':
     console.log('in reducer ', action)
      return { ...state, calendarData: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};```

Do you get that log? what does the action include?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara I got my array of objects: 
`in reducer  Object {
  "payload": Array [
    Object {
      "date": "2018-Sep-22",
      "id": 0,
      "uri": "http://www.someURL.com",
    }, and so on...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155104/discussion-between-matthew-barbara-and-user3934205).

Comment: @user3934205 Since you seemed to be keen on learning more on react and redux, have a look at my answer in this question regarding redux: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371129/is-rewriting-state-computationally-expensive-in-redux/46371232#46371232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a [lengthy chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155104/discussion-between-matthew-barbara-and-user3934205) I've figured out what was wrong. Unfortunately for many of us, React, just like native JavaScript, is very good at letting you place your code improperly.

You were configuring your route within a component and had plenty of logic in the [life cycle functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), one of which was dispatching data to the store which was never reaching your reducers.

Your problem can be solved, as proven in our chat, by separating your `action` code inside your `App.js` to a dedicated `action.js` file and then importing and adding the same function to  `mapDispatchToProps` inside your `Home.jsx`. And finally, on `componentWillMount()` of `Home.jsx` you invoke the action by `this.props.actionName()`

Your code does not seem to follow any conventions recommended by Reacts developers themselves.

If you want to improve your React's programming skills along with your programming skills in general, I recommend you the following [Udemy course by Stephen Grider](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/v4/overview).

Comment: Since you've had many of your code in one file, You need to be aware of the importance of coding separation of concern, More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns

Answer (score 0):

Try call the props in the constructor on the component. It's a good debut to debug 
Hope it helps

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {
            calendarData: props.calendarData
    };
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.calendarData !== nextProps.calendarData) {
        this.setState({
            calendarData: nextProps.calendarData,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve the issue. It's not necessary to call props in the constructor. Let me know if it does tho!

Comment: No it's not necessary but it's a good start to debug. If we could have more code we could figure out the issue and correct. I could be we the way he combines de reducers